# How do I change the value of an item in a Flex ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, arraycollection

I have an ArrayCollection with values predefined. I want to assign a new value to items in the arrayCollection but can not figure out how. Basically I want to do something like this:  acGuages.itemUpdated(0).thevalue = 90; (Changing the value from 25 to 90).  Thanks.

```
    private var arrayGuages:Array=[
        {thevalue:"25",height:"115"},
        {thevalue:"45",height:"115"},
        {thevalue:"15",height:"115"},
        {thevalue:"95",height:"115"},
        ];

    [Bindable] 
    public var acGuages:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(arrayGuages);

    acGuages.itemUpdated(0).thevalue = 90;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayCollection supports random access to its elements, just like Array. In other words, your line:

```
acGuages.itemUpdated(0).thevalue = 90;
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
acGuages[0].thevalue = 90;
```

And it should all work as expected.

Comment: Great, thanks. I also updated it so it was being set in an initialize function. 


  public function int():void {
   acGuages[0].thevalue = 90;
   acGuages.refresh();
   
   
   }

Comment: Glad it worked :)

FYI, you probably don't need the call to refresh() in your init function. If memory serves me correctly, refresh() is only needed if you're applying a filter or a sort.